# JavaScript Resource while in a loop

Tags: javascript, intervals

I have a small script...

```
var foo = function (){
   ... Some stuff here ...

   setTimeout(foo, 1);
}
foo();
```

So basically I am asking foo to call itself once it's finished giving it 1 millisecond break,

So this will run almost forever until browser refresh etc...

**Question:**

I want to avoid overwhelming the browsers or causing crashes is this a bad idea, or is there something I need to consider to avoid any crashes?

The idea would be it just runs through itself and wait's for something to happen then do something about it.

Comment: This won't continue to run the function, it runs it once after a ms (you probably want `setInterval`) -- Either way, it's probably a bad idea to run this function ever ms for eternity. What's your overall goal?

Comment: this is not an uncommon practice, however do you really need the 1ms? most browsers will not run this below 4ms and most users wouldn't notice a 100ms delay on actions.

Comment: it would if you call foo() once ... sorry I'll put that in ...

Comment: @asawyer I don't think that's a great idea, if you are halfway of processing the interval you then cancel it, and re-start it, then it's a bit useless, I suppose increasing milliseconds does not change my goal. but yeah, I am just being a bit over cautious

Comment: Ignore that you had the correct time function, I misread it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you have the long and short of it. That's the basic pattern, though you may want to make it execute at least once first. ;-)

```
(function(){
  var foo = function(){
    setTimeout(foo, 1e3);
  }();
})();
```

Though I doubt it will execute every 1ms (and whatever you're doing can't need to be *that* often, can it?). If this is testing something form a server, look at using long polling. If you're checking for a change in the browser, look at binding to specific events and not constantly checking for a delta.

Comment: `1e3` isn't that a really large number?

Comment: oh, that's news to me :) cheers I think this will do for now, until I do some more digging later on.